# Android app few functionality not working in kitkat version but working properly on other versions

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.threedb"
        minSdkVersion 15
       // targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

This code I have written in gradle but few functionality like creating new message and adding image from gallery is not working in kitkat version. Please help